# How to receive data from Arduino to Android with Bluetooth serial?

Tags: android, bluetooth, serial-port, controls, arduino

I'm trying to use an Android device to control an Arduino through Bluetooth. I'm able to control an LED and a few components on the Arduino. But I don't know how to have Android receive data from the Arduino similar to how the [BlueTerm](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.pymasde.blueterm) app works. Can any one can help me with this? I don't want to use the [Amarino](http://www.amarino-toolkit.net/) library because I don't want to have to use an extra `.jar`.

Answer (score 3):

See this work example: [Data transfer between Android and Arduino via Bluetooth](http://english.cxem.net/arduino/arduino5.php)